# Setting array values in $_SESSION through an accessor method

Tags: php, arrays, session, php-5.3

Can anyone please explain to me why the following code does not set the values on the array as expected? $_SESSION['foo'] stays empty, even after assigning time() and rand(). I've checked, the __get accessor method is actually called when assigning the variables but they aren't stored for one reason or another.

```
$test = Session::getSession('test');
$test->foo = array();
$test->foo[] = time();
$test->foo['baz'] = rand(1,9);
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Using this simple Session wrapper

```
class Session 
{

    protected $namespace = null;

    public static function getSession($namespace) 
    {
        return new Session($namespace);
    }

    public static function destroySession($namespace) 
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION[$namespace])) {
            unset($_SESSION[$namespace]);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private function __construct($namespace) 
    {
        $this->namespace = $namespace;

        if(!isset($_SESSION[$namespace])) {
            $_SESSION[$namespace] = null;
        }
    }

    public function &__get($name)
    {
        return (isset($_SESSION[$this->namespace][$name])) ? $_SESSION[$this->namespace][$name] : null;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $_SESSION[$this->namespace][$name] = $value;
    }

}
```

In case it might be relevant, i'm using php 5.3.6

Comment: That always bothered me too, so +1. But if you make an array, assign time and rand() and then set it to $test->foo it works...

Comment: @NoBBy: yea, that's something i've tried and works but unfortunately isn't foolproof so i'd rather not use it in our app :) You never know.

Comment: I'm getting the following notices: "Indirect modification of overloaded property Session::$foo has no effect" and "Only variable references should be returned by reference".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I 'm not sure if this can be made to work at all.

For one, to [return by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php) you should add the `&` operator at the call site as well. I 'm not sure how that might be possible without screwing up the nice syntax you 're trying to achieve.

Also, you cannot return expressions by reference (only variables). So this won't work:

```
public function &__get($name)
{
    return (isset($_SESSION[$this->namespace][$name])) 
        ? $_SESSION[$this->namespace][$name] 
        : null;
}
```

At the very least it should be written as

```
public function &__get($name)
{
    $value = isset($_SESSION[$this->namespace][$name])
             ? $_SESSION[$this->namespace][$name]
             : null;
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: Apparently the php internals work in a way that the __get magic method always returns values as read-only, no matter what the reference indicator says. So as far as i can tell there is no way to achieve what we want here unless we extend the library beyond recognition, might as well use Zend_Session then. (source: http://derickrethans.nl/overloaded-properties-get.html).